Failing Github Actions - No such file or directory
I have been trying to automate a GitHub workflow using Sphinx to document some Python docs that I have written. The goal is to run the 'make html' and 'make latex' after any modifications are made to keep the documentation up-to-date. I have created a simple workflow but when I run it with GitHub actions I get the error:
Run make html
Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/Repo_Name/Repo_Name/Directory_Name/docs/python'. No such file or directory

I'm not sure if this has to do with the way I have the environment set up or if it's something in the actions workflow itself? I've tried running the workflow locally using nektos act and it seems to work, so not sure why it doesn't work here.
This is what I have so far for the workflow:
name: Sphinx documentation generation
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
  workflow_call:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-python-docs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.10' 

    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install sphinx
        pip install -r requirements.txt    

    - name: Build HTML
      run: make html
      working-directory: Directory_Name/docs/python

    - name: Build LaTeX
      run: make latex
      working-directory: Directory_Name/docs/python

    - name: Upload HTML
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: python-html-docs
        path: Directory_Name/docs/python/_build/html

    - name: Upload LaTeX
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: python-pdf-docs
        path: Directory_Name/docs/python/_build/latex`

I've tried solutions for similar issues but none of the solutions have worked for me. This is my first time using GitHub actions so I'm not sure if I'm going wrong somewhere or if there's something I've missed, but would appreciate any feedback or suggestions.
